# What is the difference?

Tags: differences, word-usage

Hello I was wondering what the difference was between these:

> - I was having the man leave.
> - I was having the man leaving.
> - I had the man leaving.
> - I had the man leave.

are some of these even correct?

and what about these ones:

> - The book had me getting bored.
> - The book had me get bored.
> - The book had me bored.

*Getting* here is intended to be used instead of *becoming* as in entering the state of, but I'm not sure if this usage makes any sense given the numerous purposes of the verb have.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really need to visit http://ell.stackechange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three options in the second set are *grammatically* correct, but in my view, not the best way to express what you want. A book, as an inanimate object, cannot have *had* you do anything. Better in those cases to switch the subject and object so that "I" is the subject, and "the book" the object. So

- I was getting bored with the book.
- I got bored with the book.
- I was bored with the book.

As to the first set, about the man leaving, context is the key here, as in the correct context, all of them might be suitable. If there was someone at some place where the person should not be, the last, "I had the man leave" is correct. If the man had acceded to your request to leave, and you were narrating about something that happened while he was departing, "I had the man leaving" would express this quite nicely ("I had the man leaving when the tire on his car went flat"). "I was having the man leave" would be proper if narrating about something that happened while you were making the request ("I was having the man leave when the alarm sounded.") Finally, the last option "I was having the man leaving", is at best awkward as it stands, but there could be situations where it would be correct, if you were asking someone departing somewhere to do something as in "I was having the man leaving turn right when the tree branch fell on his car."

Comment: I don't see how the three in the second set are at all grammatical.

Comment: I think it's okay to say that a book "has" you do something. It's personification. "The book had me on the edge of my seat", "The book had me bored by the third page". If you are following directions in the book: "The book had me do this or that".

Answer (score 1):

All these examples are circuitous forms of vernacular.
In the first list, the first three sentences are informal vernacular. 
The fourth is a formal and correctly constructed English sentence. 
In the second list all are informal vernacular and could have been 
expressed simpler in formal english as either of the following two examples:

1. The book was boring.
2. The book bored me.

Consider the two sentences below. They both have the same meaning, but the first 
example is expressed in simple formal English, whilst the second is a colourful imitation of my local area's vernacular, and an example of how a local person might express the same sentiment verbally.

1. "I won't abide cheeky children."
2. "I won't be having no nippers mouthing-off at me an' giving me lip"

By its nature vernacular is long-winded and circuitous, but helpful for dramatic effect when used as direct-speech between quotation marks. To read an example of a downloadable comical book written entirely in vernacular for effect - search the internet for

> "the specialist" charles sale filetype:pdf